# Bootstrap Modal Popups and Collapsible lists fail to appear in production

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog

This is a strange one...

I've got collapsible controls like such:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#meals">Meals</button>
<div id="meals" class="collapse">...</div>
```

And I've got modal dialogs like such:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal20190401" class="crud-edit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
<div id="editModal20190401" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And both work fine, in a debug build.  But they both fail in every instance (and seemingly every browser) on a release build on a live server.  For the collapsible controls, you can see them expand or collapse (e.g. the animation works fine), but once it's fully expanded, it just pops back out of existence, like it's display:none.  For the modal dialogs, they clearly exists because they block input to the rest of the page (and I can use the Inspect to verify that the elements are, in fact, where they should be), but they're always invisible.

I've tried disabling all browser extensions, using clean extensionless browsers, clearing cookies, everything.  But since all this is supposed to be built-in functionality, and it does work in debug, I'm not even sure where to begin debugging this.  A push in the right direction would be much appreciated.

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.1 with Bootstrap 4-1.

**Edit:**
Here's a link to a unit test for the problem with the modal dialog: https://lisa3dev.slamgmt.com/TestPopup

Again, that page works fine in the local development build.

Comment: So you are saying this thing works on your development build and doesn't work on the production build ? can you share a link to the production build ? or somehow may be replicate this issue in some jsfiddle or something ?

Comment: Okay, I made a no-auth test page.  Edited question to include the link.

Comment: Cannot reach the link

Comment: @Towkir, what do you mean?  Like, it 404s?

Comment: No, `This site can’t be reached lisa3dev.slamgmt.com’s server IP address could not be found.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`

Comment: Looks like the DNS isn't propagating outside of US/CA/UK.  I'll have to look into that separately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Man, that site is a mess. I managed to access it via VPN.

This has multiple versions of Bootstrap CSS and JS added.
I would ask you to fix all those conflicts.

But if you can't, or want e temporary fix while fixing the rest of it.

You can add a `show` class to your modal

```
<div id="editModal20190401" class="modal fade show" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** this is a workaround for your scenario. But I **highly recommend**  you to fix all those conflicts and move to a specific version of Bootstrap.

**Update:**
add this stylesheet to upgrade to `bootstrap 4`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

also, add all these scripts :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**Make sure** no other `bootstrap` or `jquery` or `popper` version is added

Comment: Definitely want it done right.  Looks like this is a result of a beginner attempt to upgrade from .NET Core's default bootstrap v3.3.7 to v4.x to include a dependency that requires the later version.  So, the correct bootstrap version for this project should be 4.1.  I've removed the offending include for v3.3.7 (so there shouldn't be a conflict anymore, right?), but it doesn't seem to fix the problem on it's own.  Does 4.1 need the "show" class in the modal or is there still another underlying problem?

Comment: looks like you missed to add the scripts now. answer updated. check now

Comment: No, I don't want to reference an external version of bootstrap though.  We've got a modified version of 4.1 installed that should be used.  (modification is just to CSS, mostly colors, not to JS).

Comment: then you should add the script from that minified version, currently there is not bootstrap script added at all, the modal mechanism works with the script. no need to add from an external link. but make sure to add the script

Comment: And that did the trick.  The root cause was that I was missing the correctly versioned bootstrap script import.  Thanks!